# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) - accessing shape

Tags: python, numpy, pca, face-recognition, principal-components

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to apply Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to a set of images. I want to put the images in a matrix to be able to perform PCA.  I am still at the beginning but I am having errors.

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import os

#insert images to matrix
dirname = 'C:\Users\Karim\Downloads\shp_marcel_train\Marcel-Train\A'
X = [np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fn))) for fn in os.listdir(dirname)]

#get dimensions
num_data,dim = X.shape
```

It gives `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

anyone can help?

a link to a detailed tutorial would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

`[np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fn))) for fn in os.listdir(dirname)]`

It would return an array, which is stored in local variable `X`

You are trying to extract variables from a list, and hence the error.

The individual elements within `X` have the shape attributes. Hence, you need to do something like this (modify it according to the datastructure `shape` is defined as )

`dim0 = X[0].shape` and so on

Comment: It would return a ___list___, which is stored in local variable `X`

Answer (score 2):

As you've defined it, `X` is a list:

```
X = [... for fn in ...]
```

Python lists do not have a shape attribute. Inside this list are NumPy arrays which *do* have a shape attribute. So you could say

```
num_data = len(X)
shape_of_first_array = X[0].shape
```

(You didn't explain what `dim` is supposed to represent...)

---

Here is an [example of face recognition](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scikit-learn/index.html#id9) done with PCA and a State Vector Machine. Here is [another related example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html).